# Intel XDK IDE can't find CODE and DESIGN buttons

Tags: intel-xdk

I'm using the Intel XDK and I can't find the stupid buttons that switch between CODE and DESIGN mode. According to the Intel "getting started" video it should be here:

[image]

but mine looks like this:
[image]

I have to believe I'm missing something easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that when you start a new project, you need to choose "app designer" AT THAT TIME, otherwise it will be the raw code project page.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can only "design" an App Designer layout. If you have an App Designer project open, the code and design buttons will only appear when you have selected the index.html file, since that is the file that you are editing when you are using the "design" button.